# On Fourier coefficients of a newform.

Tags: modular-forms

Let $f\in S^\text{new}_k(Γ_0(N))$ be a $\text{newform}$ . If I know $a_p(f)=0$, then what is $a_{p^2}(f)$?
Is it zero or some power (in terms of weight k) of $p$? 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You mean $a_{p^2}(f)$ ? If $a_1 = 1$ then 
$a_{p^2} = a_p^2-1_{p\, \nmid \,N} \, p^{k-1} $ so no if $p \nmid N$

Comment: yes $a_{p^2}(f)$, I edited in the question.

Comment: @reuns, would you be willing to post that as an answer?